# Stucked HDP adding host

Tags: ambari

I have an HDP cluster with 2 nodes, we had some problem and 1 host heartbeat was lost without any chance to recover it as the machine failed so we finally re-install Ubuntu and configure it again.

It was impossible to recover the host in ambari (trying to give same FQDN, ip, configuration,...) so I tried to change hostname and add it as a completely new host.

I did get able to complete installation step 2 with 'SUCCESS' status, but it get stucked whith the following message 'Please wait while the hosts are being checked for potential problems...' for hours.

I attach ambari-server log, ambari-agent log ambari registration log and error image.

Do you have some idea about what is happening and how to solve it?

Thanks.

[ambari-server.log](https://pastebin.com/evJ3BkkQ)

```
12 jun 2018 09:34:55,667  WARN [ambari-action-scheduler] ExecutionCommandWrapper:185 - Unable to lookup the cluster by ID; assuming that there is no cluster and therefore no configs for this execution command: Cluster not found, clusterName=clusterID=-1
12 jun 2018 09:34:56,675  WARN [ambari-action-scheduler] ExecutionCommandWrapper:185 - Unable to lookup the cluster by ID; assuming that there is no cluster and therefore no configs for this execution command: Cluster not found, clusterName=clusterID=-1
12 jun 2018 09:34:57,683  WARN [ambari-action-scheduler] ExecutionCommandWrapper:185 - Unable to lookup the cluster by ID; assuming that there is no cluster and therefore no configs for this execution command: Cluster not found, clusterName=clusterID=-1
```

[ambari-agent.log](https://pastebin.com/ZHC7fGAq)

```
INFO 2018-06-12 09:00:16,026 Controller.py:512 - Registration response from bigdata was OK
INFO 2018-06-12 09:00:16,026 Controller.py:517 - Resetting ActionQueue...
INFO 2018-06-12 09:00:26,035 Controller.py:304 - Heartbeat (response id = 0) with server is running...
INFO 2018-06-12 09:00:26,036 Controller.py:311 - Building heartbeat message
INFO 2018-06-12 09:00:26,037 Heartbeat.py:90 - Adding host info/state to heartbeat message.
INFO 2018-06-12 09:00:26,099 logger.py:75 - Testing the JVM's JCE policy to see it if supports an unlimited key length.
INFO 2018-06-12 09:00:26,168 Hardware.py:176 - Some mount points were ignored: /dev, /run, /, /dev/shm, /run/lock, /sys/fs/cgroup, /boot, /run/user/1000, /run/user/0, /run/user/994
INFO 2018-06-12 09:00:26,169 Controller.py:320 - Sending Heartbeat (id = 0)
INFO 2018-06-12 09:00:26,174 Controller.py:332 - Heartbeat response received (id = 1)
INFO 2018-06-12 09:00:26,174 Controller.py:341 - Heartbeat interval is 10 seconds
INFO 2018-06-12 09:00:26,174 Controller.py:377 - Updating configurations from heartbeat
INFO 2018-06-12 09:00:26,174 Controller.py:386 - Adding cancel/execution commands
INFO 2018-06-12 09:00:26,174 Controller.py:403 - Adding recovery commands
INFO 2018-06-12 09:00:26,174 Controller.py:471 - Waiting 9.9 for next heartbeat
INFO 2018-06-12 09:00:36,075 Controller.py:478 - Wait for next heartbeat over
```

[registration log](https://pastebin.com/h1QXbZmz)

```
INFO 2018-06-12 09:34:38,350 Controller.py:512 - Registration response from bigdata was OK
INFO 2018-06-12 09:34:38,350 Controller.py:517 - Resetting ActionQueue...
', None)

Connection to master.es closed.
SSH command execution finished
host=master.es, exitcode=0
Command end time 2018-06-12 09:34:38

Registering with the server...
Registering with the server...
```

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

Do an ambari-agent reset on all nodes.

Change cluster name.